# async WebRequest troubles

Tags: async-await, mstest, webrequest

I am trying to create some regression tests that make async calls to our API.  I have been getting a null reference error consistently no matter what I try.  I have tried several different ways of calling the request to no avail.  I'm at my wit's end.  I can put a breakpoint in the code to check the URL and run that URL in Postman and it returns data as expected.  I am passing a few headers but nothing out of the ordinary.

Below is the stack trace and my code.  Can anyone see what I am missing?

Thanks

`` <GetApiResponse>d__17`1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\foo\Documents\test.api\Common\Base.cs:line 199
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Test.API.ResultsTest.<ResultsAPI_SortByLowToHigh>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\voo\Documents\test.api\ResultsTest.cs:line 74
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Result Message: 
Test method Test.API.ResultsAPI_SortByLowToHigh threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ``

```
try
{
    var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    webRequest.Headers.Add("ApiVersion", "1");
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Country-Code", "US");
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Currency-Code", "USD");

    Task<WebResponse> responseTask = webRequest.GetResponseAsync();

    using (var webResponse = await responseTask)
    {
        using (var sres = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            if (sres != null) await sres.CopyToAsync((ms));
            ms.Position = 0;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                JsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JsonResponse))
    {
        response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResponse>(JsonResponse);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(typeof(ServiceResponse).Name + " API returned null Response");
    }
    return response;
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    ErrorMsg.AppendLine(e.Message);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Why not use HttpClient to talk to the API? Or [Flurl](https://flurl.io/) (my favorite)? or [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)? That will remove a lot of the boilerplate from this code, reduce the chance for a coding mistake, be easier to maintain, and allow you to focus on actually writing tests. With Flurl, this could be as easy as `await  "http://api.foo.com".WithHeader("ApiVersion", "1").GetJsonAsync<ServiceResponse>();` (well you have two more headers but I think you get the idea)

Comment: The stack trace you copied says the null reference exception happened on line 74. Which line is line 74?

Comment: Line 74:

using (var webResponse = await responseTask) . which is affectively failing on GetResponseAsync.

Comment: @mason Our applications that call the API use WebRequest or httpClient.  I would like to keep the tests as close to the apps as possible.  I will try httpClient.  It is strange that WebRequest works in the app but not in the tests.

Comment: I switched to HttpClient and I'm still getting the error.  It must be something in the return value but hard to debug if I can't see it before it throws the exception.

Comment: Turns out it was a tls issue.  Adding this line before the call fixed the issue.

                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Rhonda